# Log when a website is published

Tags: azure-devops

Does VS Teams services have an agent to log when a website is published in Visual Studio 2015? I am new to Team Services. I have a small team of developers, 4 including myself. We have recently migrated from TFS 2010 to Team Services. Part of our PCI compliance, we need to log when our sites are published. We currently publish to an IIS server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, all actions are in local and not related to VS Team Services, so VS Team Service can’t log anything.

You can build and publish/deploy the web app to IIS through VS Team Service build and release system, then you can check the related information of that build/release (e.g. detail build/release log)

More information, you can refer to this article: [Deploy your Web Deploy package to IIS servers](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-deploygroups)